# Encrypting Password across different systems in Powershell

Tags: powershell, encryption, dns, subdomain

I am writing a PowerShell script to automate adding systems to domain but the issue is encrypting the password. I used the steps provided in the below link but the steps works only on the system I generated the encrypted password.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Encrypt-Password-and-use-dd07f253

I keep getting is error - 'convertto-string: key not valid for use in specified state"

I am using the same user account to add to the domain as I built the credentials with initially, so I believe that the computer is rejecting these credentials because the SID has changed. Please suggest what can I do.

Comment: Have it be part of the build process.

Comment: The article literally says to only encrypt on the machine where you plan to use it.

Comment: Instead of trying to secure such an account by those means, why not create a special account that isn't able to logon but able to join computers to the domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use your script on other systems, they are not aware of the **key** that was used to encrypt the password.  With the **key**, you can use it on different systems.  You can generate your own AES key and use it with the cmdlets on different systems. You can find more details on using a key with `ConvertTo-SecureString` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring?view=powershell-5.1)